# Windows10 .exe ICON is missing

Tags: icons, windows-10

I'm trying to fix Windows context menu slow issue, right click menu is very slow.

I've done below steps:

1. Using ShellExView to disable some external items, no Microsoft item is disabled.
2. Remove HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\NvCplDesktopContext
3. Reboot PC

Now context menu speed issue is fixed, but lots of exe icon are missing after this, like notepad++ or IE shortcuts are shown as blank file icon.

[[Please click here] for IE icon screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dql9H.png)

Uninstall and re-install tool still can NOT fix this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Manually fixed the issue by extracting icon from exe file then use extracted icon.
Seems like icon cache is broken.

Comment: Can only change shortcut icon. Exe is still empty file icon.

Comment: Tried below steps but the problem is still there.                                      1. Press Ctrl-Shift-Escape to get the task manager.
2. In the Processes tab, click on explorer.exe and click End Process. You'll get a confirmation dialog. Click "End Process" to confirm.
3. From the File menu (still in the task manager), choose New Task (Run...).
4. Copy/paste/enter the following command in the run box:
Code:
cmd /c del %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db /a
5. Open the Run box again with File --> New Task (Run...). This time, enter this command:
Code:
explorer.exe

Comment: Tried delete every .db inside C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer, but still failed.

Comment: Tried method mention in this page. http://superuser.com/questions/878761/windows-icon-cache-does-not-exist        Now %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db is appeared but still failed of showing some icons.

Comment: Rebuild ICON Cache doesn't help.

Comment: After installing the latest windows update, everything is back to normal.